# modeling a real world problem into java classes

Tags: java, oop

How can i model foollwing problem statatement into java classe?

I have a class vehincle.

- Vehicles can be of type Trucks, Cars, Scooters, motorcycles.
- Vehicle has a engine.
- engine shold have following contraints

  - Petrol Engine and Diesel Engine are types of Engines
  - Truck comes with 4 stroke, 12 cylinder Diesel Engine
  - Car can have either 4 stroke Petrol Engine or 4 stroke  Diesel Engine
  - Car can have either 4 Cylinder Engine or 6 Cylinder Engine.
  - Motorcycle can have 4 stroke single Cylinder Petrol Engine or 4 stroke twin-cylinder Petrol engine.
  - Scooters can have Single Cylinder 2 Stroke Petrol Engine or Single Cylinder 4 stroke Petrol Engine.
- Each engine consists of

  - Number of cylinders [1/2/4/6/12 only]
  - Number of strokes [2/4 only].
  - ‘Engine Number’ is always 6 characters alphanumeric.
- Diesel engine always comes with 4 strokes but Petrol engine can come with either 2 strokes or 4 strokes.
- Only Petrol engines have Spark plugs [One per cylinder]. Diesel Engine cannot have Spark plugs.
- Sparkplug just has sequence number [e.g Car with 6 Cylinder Engine will have Sparkplugs SP1, SP2,  SP3, SP4, SP5, SP6]
- Only Trucks and Cars have Oil Pump.
- Each Oil pump has

  - Identification number 6 char alphanumeric
  - Capacity in cubic centimeters(cc) per seconds [value can be between 1-5]

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? The specifications you have fit perfectly into a class hierarchy.

Comment: am not getting how should i model it into java classes

Comment: can anyone provide me with guidelines to desing classes for it?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds very much like a beginner OOP task. In this case you're going to model each class of *things* in the real world as classes in your class model. That is, there will be a class `Vehicle`, `Engine`, `SparkPlug`, etc.

Then those classes have certain relationships, such as `DieselEngine` being a kind of `Engine`. You should have learned that *inheritance* can be used to model such a relationship.

Furthermore, some things are composed of other things, such as `PetrolEngine` having a `SparkPlug`. Classes can have *attributes* as you probably know already. Use them accordingly.

In UML the two things you need here for a class diagram would be *generalization* and *composition*.

Also, I'm sure if you ask your fellow students you can together come up with a solution. That's usually easier than dumping the task description into a forum or Q&A site and waiting for ready-made solutions.

Comment: +1 for not giving too much away. (Not sure it's worth mentioning UML, though - I don't think that would be used at a beginner level)

Comment: @David: At least basic class diagrams were part of our schedule almost at the same time as generic OO modeling.